# Why doesn't margin: 0, auto; work?

Tags: css

Why doesn't this center `#block1` and `#block2`?

```
<div id="superwrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        a
        <div id="block1">
            pippo
        </div>
        <div id="block2">
            pluto
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
div#superwrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:210px;
    background-color:#FFFFCC;
    border:dotted;
}

div#wrapper {
    text-align:left;
    width:500px;
    heigth:205px;
    margin:0,auto;
    border:dotted;
}

div#block1 {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:dotted;
}

div#block2 {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:dotted;
}
```

Comment: it would be `margin: 0 auto;`. The comma is your problem, I believe.

Comment: You're not closing your superwrapper DIV in that code above. Also you've spelt 'height' wrong in the WRAPPER CSS.

Comment: @BillyMoat: `superwrapper` was closed, it was just hiding. :)

Comment: corrected the spelling error: no way to center anything :-(

Answer (score 6):

```css
margin: 0, auto;
```

The comma here is not the correct syntax. It should be just a space:

```css
margin: 0 auto;
```

Also, as @BillyMoat points out, `heigth` should be `height`.

Comment: @MassimoIvaldi: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? [It works for me...](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/sd6F6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
div#wrapper {
    text-align:left;
    width:500px;
    heigth:205px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare doctype at the start of the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the units for the margin. Try something like:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started two days ago to learn CSS and used this question to get more familiar with margins. Hope I do not confuse you with my statements below.

Anyway, I haven't found anything in the original code which would tell the browser to put block1 and block2 into the center.

My solution is the following: use float:right; for block2. Then add margins for block1 and block2. As all blocks use a fixed width, you can calculate that the left (block1) and right (block2) margin must be set to 33px. The border takes a couple of pixels (default = medium; was not able to find out how many pixels are used for medium). At the end, it looks as 27px is quite ok.

Here the code:

```
div#superwrapper {
width:100%;
height:210px;
background-color:#FFFFCC;
border:dotted;
}

div#wrapper {
text-align:left;
width:500px;
height:205px;
margin:0 auto;
border:dotted;
}

div#block1 {
text-align:left;
float:left;
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:dotted;
margin: 0 0 0 27px;
}

div#block2 {
text-align:left;
float:right; 
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:dotted;
margin: 0 27px 0 0;
}
```

Hope that helps and does the trick?